# Expanding a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given a matrix, such as:

```
1 0 0
0 1 1
1 1 0
```

I would like to expand each element to a "sub-matrix" of size AxA, e.g., 3x3, the result will be:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

What is the *fastest* way of doing it in Python using numpy (or PyTorch)?

Comment: Define "fastest". Or is fast and readable good enough?

Comment: I just wonder how I can avoid using two loops, since I have plenty of those matrices (I have 4D matrices).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you're describing is the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product):

Use **`np.kron`**

> Computes the Kronecker product, a composite array made of blocks of the second array scaled by the first.

```
x = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]])

np.kron(x, np.ones((3, 3)))

array([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```